# React handling temporary data

Tags: reactjs

What is the right way or best way to handle "temporary" states in react? For example, if I have some data that I want to edit when my edit state is true, how do I persist it so that when a user clicks save the date us saved to the database, but when they click cancel it is destroyed or simply not applied. What I've thought of is having a second state variable that would hold the temporary edits to the data. Is that the react way?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is not a React field, as you talk about server communication. React is about V at MVC paradigm, it is all about View, but if you want to know in general - where to store data at React app, I can advise [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) as a global storage and good M and C letters for MVC (model and controller).